# How can I handle inbound emails via SMTP in Azure

Tags: c#, email, azure, smtp

I would like to all inbound emails to a specific domain to be handled by an SMTP server on Azure (probably in a worker role) and for it to add all emails to an Azure Queue so I can then handle each email and apply specific business rules that may include forwarding the original email to a new email address (and hence I would like to preserve the entire email message).

I have found this article

http://blog.smarx.com/posts/emailtheinternet-com-sending-and-receiving-email-in-windows-azure

But it is now nearly 5 years old and one of the components (CSES) that is required is no longer available on Sourceforge.

Anyone got any suggestions? Examples? Articles they could point me at?

Cheers Mike

Comment: You should look at inbound hooks from SendGrid which is the Azure-prefered SMTP provider (there's no native feature like SES on AWS). https://sendgrid.com/blog/sendgrids-parse-api-parsing-incoming-email-is-now-faster-and-easier/

Comment: I am looking at that as a possibility but there are two downsides to that approach. Firstly, it is not clear if some of the information in the email is lost during the parsing process. Secondly, and this is very important as I could be handling a lot of emails, there is a cost associated with it. I would like to know if I could create a solution hosted entirely within Azure so that I can compare the two.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do this - but I wouldn't recommend it for reasons I will explain below, unless you are talking about tens of millions of emails. I did look into this for similar reasons to you a few years ago and ended going with a service (Postmark in my case) instead.

In short, you'd need to set up a Worker role with a TCP Listener on port 25 and port 465. You then need to write the code that can "talk SMTP" and, as you mention, CSES is a starting point but I'm pretty sure you'd effectively have to write your own protocol parser. The good news is that the SMTP protocol is pretty simple. The bad news is that it has been bastardised over the years and you'd have to handle things like TLS (port 465) etc. In short, you need to grab the SMTP spec and start writing a lot of code. It would probably be sensible to start with CSES and go from there.

However, there are good reasons why this is unlikely to be cost effective for you. I don't know the pricing structure with Sendgrid; I use Postmark, but I suspect they are similar. With volume pricing I pay something like £1,000 for 2 million emails if memory serves.

If you do write your own, you have to write and maintain the code and fix any bugs. You also have to deal with resilience, so you will probably need two workers or VMs - and you will probably want another two in another DC just to protect from DC failures (they are rare, but they do happen). You will also need to write fail-over code for your  queues, just in case the queue infrastructure in your DC is having problems. So, you end up with quite a few servers and a lot of code to write and maintain.

If the volume of emails you expect is truly so high that the cost of using a service like Sendgrid or Postmark will outstrip that cost then you just have to go that way and there is no real shortcut. Also, I will admit, I haven't then answered your real question.

If you don't yet know what volume you will get, why don't you use one of the services for now and write this other code when the cost for using the service starts becoming so big that it is cost-effective to write it yourself?

Comment: Do you know if CSES even still exists? I can't find the binaries.

Comment: And I appreciate you comments and will certainly looking into all the options.

Comment: I think you can download the source from here: http://www.ericdaugherty.com/dev/cses/ It links to Soureforge but the links seem to work.

Comment: That is really weird. The Sourceforge link didn't work for me yesterday. Works fine now.